# Css classes not added in new layout template in WebSphere Portal

Tags: css, websphere-portal

I'm trying to create a custom layout template. I'm following these guide lines:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Page_Builder-Creating_Custom_Page_Layouts_WP7_

When I upload, the layout.html is found and used by the server. The problem is that the new classes I've added to the layout.css does not come in to effect. When I inspect the page source, the divs have my classes, but the classes are not added to any css-file. I've searched through them all (from view source of the rendered page).

(I have restarted the server, emptied the temp dirs on server, reloaded in browser with empty cache)

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a class name to an element does not in any way create that class in any css entry. You will have to manually add that class to the css along with any rules for styling you are wishing to have in place.